# How to set breakpoint in the middle of methods chain

Tags: javascript, jquery

For example, How could I put `debugger;` after `.attr("class", "bar")`
So that I can debug at the breakpoint

Thanks

### Before

```
svg.selectAll(".bar")
    .data(data)
  .enter()
    .append("rect")
    .attr("class", "bar")
    .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.num); })
    .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.letter); })
    .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
```

### I expect I can debug like this

```
svg.selectAll(".bar")
    .data(data)
  .enter()
    .append("rect")
    .attr("class", "bar")
    .debugger;
    .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.num); })
    .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.letter); })
    .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
```

### UPDATE

I got the error `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function`

```
$.fn.debug = function() { debugger; return this; };

 group.selectAll("path") // bind data to empty collection as usual
        .data([data]) // what need another [] to bracket it ?
        .enter()
        .append("path")
        .debug()
        .attr("d", line)
```

Comment: You'll need to stick it inside one of the callbacks.

Answer (score 3):

You can't insert `debugger` in the middle of the chain. You have to go with approach proposed by Kevin Labécot. Or if you really want, you can write a very simple jQuery plugin and use it like this:

```
$.fn.debugger = function() { debugger; return this; }

svg.selectAll(".bar")
  .data(data)
  .enter()
    .append("rect")
    .attr("class", "bar")
    .debugger() // <--- debugger will stop here
    .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.num); })
    .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.letter); })
    .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
```

Comment: Cool idea. You can even make it library agnostic using the power of prototype chain. `Object.defineProperty(Object.prototype, 'debugger', {value: function() {debugger; return this;}, enumerable: false});`

Comment: @YuryTarabanko haha, this is smart! `"test".split('').reverse().debugger().join('')`.

Comment: Hi I got some problem, please see the update thanks :)

Comment: Are you sure you put `$.fn.debug = function() { debugger; return this; };` after `jQuery` script and before you use it?

Answer (score 0):

Something like that ?

```
svg.selectAll(".bar")
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append("rect")
    .attr("class", "bar");

debugger;

svg.selectAll(".bar")
    .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.num); })
    .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.letter); })
    .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
```